# How to add button to a view pager in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to add a button to a View Pager. Tried adding button, fragment, and layout without success.
I've also tried this: 
[Add button to ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27234817/add-button-to-viewpager)
But it didn't work.

This is my layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.airpal.yonatan.airpal.MainActivity_User">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout">
        <include layout="@layout/app_bar_layout" android:id="@+id/main_page_toolbar" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white">

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/main_tabPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>




</LinearLayout>
```

[image: pic]

This is the screen shot, I want to add the button on the bottom of the page. 
Thanks.

Comment: just use Relative layout as parent layout and align the button at the bottom...

Comment: like floating action button.. **(layout_alignParentBottom = true)**  xml if you want that button to be visible in all pages of pager..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Wrap this LinearLayout in the Relative layout. If you don't want to change the Linear layout to RelativeLayout. Here is the modified layout XML and It will display Button the Bottom Right. You can modify layout_alignParentRight to left, center depend on your need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout 
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.airpal.yonatan.airpal.MainActivity_User">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout">
            <include layout="@layout/app_bar_layout" android:id="@+id/main_page_toolbar" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/main_tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white">

            </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/main_tabPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout">

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using RelativeLayout for the root view and use :

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

With LinearLayout at root view is not possible. Also, instead of RelativeLayout, ConstraintLayout is a good alternative.